# Temprary tables on Mariadb with no activity on the server

Tags: mariadb

I have a nagios check for mariadb 10.4 server running on Debian9, WARNING - 59.92% of 670 tables were created on disk | pct_tmp_table_on_disk=59.92%;50;75 pct_tmp_table_on_disk_now=77.46%. However, there's little to no activity on the server, slow query log doesn't registered anything.
In my.cnf I have tmp_table_size          = 32M and max_heap_table_size     = 32M.
The tmpdir is /tmp and i see nothing there as well.
I am not sure if the check is wrong or is there anything that i'm missing...Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

"slow query log doesn't registered anything" -- Decrease `long_query_time` down to `1` or less.  (Even `0` if you get desperate.)

Temp tables may be in RAM or on disk, depending on several things.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for any tables that might involve temp tables.

The prime candidate for going straight to disk (and ignoring the two `...table_size` settings) is when there is any kind of `TEXT` or `BLOB` column in the query.  Another case is that it will fill up the 32M you have configured, then copy it to disk to continue.

"/tmp and i see nothing there" -- How are you looking?  The code probably creates the disk table, then "rm's" it immediately.  After that it proceeds to use it.  If a crash occurs, the file is already gone, so there is no trash left behind.  (Magic!)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I set up the query time to 1 and then to 0, I was only able to find one query with tmp_table_on_disk in 20minutes of watching them...The rest of them are:  # Full_scan: No  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: No  Tmp_table_on_disk: No